# join select and count using codeigniter and mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have three table as follow:

#### tblHelpdeskType (It need to join with tblHelpdesk)

```
HelpdeskTypeID | HelpdeskType         |  Current
        1      | Not Specified        |  -1
        2      | Feature Request      |  -1
        3      | Account Request      |  -1
        4      | Permission Requested |  -1
        5      | Bug                  |  -1
```

#### tblHelpdesk (primary table)

```
HelpdeskID||HelpdeskTypeID||HelpdeskPriorityID||RequestBy||DateTimeStamp||HelpdeskStatusID
    1         || 1            || 2                ||sothorn  || 12/12/12    || 1
    2         || 3            || 1                ||Chantra  || 12/12/12    || 1
    3         || 1            || 1                ||Lyhong   || 12/12/12    || 2
    4         || 3            || 1                ||bongthom || 12/12/12    || 1
```

#### tblHelpdeskStatus  (It need to join with tblHelpdesk )

```
HelpdeskStatusID   | HelpdeskStatus
    1                  | Pending
    2                  | View
    3                  | In treatment
    4                  | Closed
```

Result that I need is :

```
Type                  | Pending | View | In treatment | Closed  |
----------------------------------------------------------------|
Not Specified         |    1    |   1  |              |         |
----------------------------------------------------------------|
Feature Request       |    2    |      |              |         |
----------------------------------------------------------------|
Account Request       |         |      |              |         |
----------------------------------------------------------------|
Permission Requested  |         |      |              |         |
----------------------------------------------------------------|
Bug                   |         |      |              |         |
----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Show us some code that you have tried.

Comment: It mean that I select and count it Example : Type(Not Specified ) and status Pedding have 2 recorde and we count it two record to show on page